# Web Troubleshooting Email Template?

Tags: client-support

I have an issue that im sure most other web development people have which is trying to answer vague emails about website or email issues. Trying to get details such as an exact page URL or a scenario where the error occurs is like pulling teeth out.  Does anyone have a really good all-encompassing email template they use for situations like this? Something that covers browser details, scenario, page URLs etc ?

Would love suggestions on things to say to get this information and that clearly explain to the client that with so many variables we need clarification.

Comment: I guess that it is not enough to tell what information you need, but also where/how they can collect it. Lambda users are deprived.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic

Comment: I will vote yes on this sorry its a little to vague.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really an all-encompassing template for things like this; not everything is easy to convey in a form, etc.

Really, if you run a web service for a client, you should have some kind of automated bug/error reporting already in place ([Bugsnag](https://bugsnag.com/), [Sentry](https://getsentry.com), are some examples) that would alert you to something being wrong way before a client gets to you; I can typically fix a bug around 3-4 minutes after being alerted to it for simple errors. Involve a client in that, and you're talking an hour or three just to get to the bottom of something and figure out what to fix.

As for design bugs, and stuff that *you should have already agreed on well in advance with a contract*, point to your contract, or prepare invoice templates for this kind of thing, depending on the agreement you have with a client.